# How does Android application store state

Tags: android

I want to ask that where does the password gets stored after we login to the application from our phone. I need to know the mechanism of working of how the state is saved in the case of mobile applications.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: This post needs improvement. Actually what I wanted to ask was a different thing. @halfer

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific place to store the user credentials. The thing is we should be able to read and write from the place we write it.

Mainly we use `sharedPreferences` for this. This is a file that is saved in a folder that is specific to that particular app. This is cleared when we uninstall the app or clear the data. It stores data as key, value pair.

Actually we don't store the username and password. When we submit the username and password to the server, if the credentials are valid, we get a `access token` in response. That will be a string and is saved in `sharedPreferences`. Next time when we open the app, we first check whether a token is already present in the sharedPreferences. If yes we directly goto the inside of the app and any server calls can be authenticated using this token. If such token is not present, we goto login screen.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of different ways this can be implemented.

If you're using a backend service to authenticate your users such as [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) then their username and password is authenticated on the server side and you are passed back an oAuth2 token that allows the client to verify that they are authorised (logged in) to access the database. Backend API Auth implementation is very varied and depends on your Database.  (MongoDB, Amazon, Firebase etc).

Otherwise, you can use `SharedPreferences` to store whether a user is logged in or not after you have authenticated them. I wouldn't advise this implementation as it's open to exploitation and would suggest that you use the API method above and authenticate the user each time they enter your app. Authentication does not mean logging in...it mearly checks their oAuth2 token with the server to make sure it's valid.

Answer (score 1):

It's not much safe to store passwords. Usually apps store some token(Though it really depends on authentication method).
And in addition to Antonio's answer,android has released [EncryptedSharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences.html) which encrypts key & values to provide more security.

Answer (score 0):

It's saved in the database but not as plain text. Before storing it the password is hashed and when checking the login information the given password is hashed and verified with the hashed password from the database.